# Going back to the previous page with 'goto' / Sveltekit navigation

Tags: sveltekit

I normally use the following to redirect to any page without using `window.location.href` in Sveltekit

```js
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

const goSomeWhere = () :void => {
    goto('/')
}
```

But how do we make it go back to the previous page? Should I just use the vanilla JavaScript to go back?

Answer (score 16):

You can go back to the previous page by using the `afterNavigate` lifecycle.

This can be more reliable than @Jarduilno's suggestion as not every incoming link is in the same parent path.

store the pathname from the `from` URL object, and use it later in a function. **ex:** `goto(previousPage)`

```js
import { goto, afterNavigate } from '$app/navigation';
import { base } from '$app/paths'

let previousPage : string = base ;

afterNavigate(({from}) => {
   previousPage = from?.url.pathname || previousPage
})
```

Comment: once you go back to another page this way, page you came from will be "previous", so if you click button again you will go the the page you came from, thus making a loop from these two pages

Answer (score 11):

You can use the javaScript history object like this `history.back();`

Comment: It won't trigger recomposition.

Comment: Works for me. And since SvelteKit should correctly handle click on the Back button in the web browser, it should also be able to correctly handle back navigation this way (I don't think there exists a way for SvelteKit to distinguish the two ways).

Answer (score 5):

in our SvelteKit project we are sometimes navigating to previous page like in the example bellow

```
import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
import { page } from '$app/stores';

const goSomeWhereBack = () => {
    goto($page.url.pathname.substring(0, $page.url.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can made use of the [navigating store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores) from `$app/stores`.

```
import { navigating } from "$app/stores";

export const previousPage = readable(null, (set) => {
    const unsubscribe = navigating.subscribe(($navigating) => {
        // Check if `$navigating` has a value
        // because it's set to `null` after navigation is done
        if ($navigating) {
            set($navigating.from.url.pathname);
        }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
});
```

Keep in mind that this store is keeping track of the previously opened page and is not a [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). So calling `goto($previousPage)` multiple times one after the other will get you stuck in a loop.

Alternatively, if you want to use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) instead (which uses a stack), you can just call `history.back()` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842326/2419808).